# Combine multiple functions in one script in Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using code to pull data from multiple sheets.  The code is working fine, but I need to pull data from more than one location.  I'd like to pull it all at once.  The code below works fine to pull the ImportFALLOBS data (first function), but won't execute the ImportSPRINGOBS function.

```
const ids = [
  '1-PzUz2dlsLwA7lcndyWUZk4olgccE31jje8_JakZxXQ'
  
]
function ImportFALLOBS() {
  let result = []
  ids.forEach((id, i) => {
    let [headers, ...data] = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName('FALL OBS').getRange(5,1,1,13).getValues()
    if (i == 0) { result.push(headers.flat()) }
    data.forEach(r => result.push(r))
  })
  var master = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('FALLOBSIMPORT') 
  master.clearContents()
  master.getRange(2, 1, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result)
}

function ImportSPRINGOBS() {
  let result = []
  ids.forEach((id, i) => {
    let [headers, ...data] = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName('SPRING OBS').getRange(5,1,1,13).getValues()
    if (i == 0) { result.push(headers.flat()) }
    data.forEach(r => result.push(r))
  })
  var master = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SPRINGOBSIMPORT') 
  master.clearContents()
  master.getRange(2, 1, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result)
}
```

Comment: How and where are `ImportFALLOBS` and `ImportSPRINGOBS` invoked (called).  I see no mechanical difference between the two so they should both work.  Unless some sheet name is misspelled.

Comment: I've doublechecked the sheet names.  I also tried creating a new script and running the springobs separately.  Then I get a SyntaxErrorr - "Identifier 'ids' has already been declared.

Comment: How are you invoking the functions?

Comment: I was able to troubleshoot it on my own!  Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your code smaller and faster by combining the common parts and just change the sheet names:

```
function ImportOBS() {
  const sheetNames = ['FALL OBS','SPRING OBS'];
  const importNames = ['FALLOBSIMPORT', 'SPRINGOBSIMPORT'];

  sheetNames.forEach((sheetName,i)=>{
      let result = []
      ids.forEach((id, i) => {
      let [headers, ...data] = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(sheetName).getRange(5,1,1,13).getValues()
      if (i == 0) { result.push(headers.flat()) }
         data.forEach(r => result.push(r))
      })
      var master = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(importNames[i]) 
      master.clearContents()
      master.getRange(2, 1, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result);
  })  
}
```

and now you have only one function: `ImportOBS`